# debug spring project with specific profile on visual studio code

Tags: spring, kotlin, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to debug a kotlin/spring project in vscode, but I can't find a way to activate the desired profile.
My `launch.json` file looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "kotlin",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Kotlin Launch",
      "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "mainClass": "my.package.ApplicationKt",
      "args": [ "--spring.profiles.active=dev" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The app starts but with no active profile. I've seen a lot of answers with different combinations: using `vmArgs` instead of `args`, `"-Dspring.profiles.active=dev"` or `[ "--spring.profiles.active", "dev" ]` or `[ "-Dspring.profiles.active", "dev"]` but nothing seems to work.

I'm using VSCode 1.63.0 with kotlin 1.5.30 and spring boot 2.4.4.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out thanks to autocomplete.

VSCode documentation is not ok. All the examples and documentation points to `vmArgs` option where, supposedly, I could set my `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev`, but that's not the case, at least for the versions I'm working on.

The correct option is not `vmArgs` but **`vmArguments`** instead.